# developブランチからmasterにマージする度にAll Branchesでの履歴が見づらくなる

Tags: git, sourcetree

developブランチからある程度の機能単位を作成するブランチ（フィーチャーブランチ？）を派生させてdevelopブランチへプルリクエストを投げてマージしています。

他の開発者のフィーチャーブランチ？がdevelopにマージされたときは、各開発者は最新のdevelopに追いつくために各自開発途中のフィーチャーブランチ？を最新developからrebaseして線をできるだけ綺麗に（直線になるように）努めています（rebaseではなくマージするときもあります）。

そのdevelopブランチがある程度進んだ段階で（開発の区切りがよい段階）でdevelopからmasterにプルリクエストを投げてマージしています。

するとSourceTreeでAll Branchesでみると画像のようにマージを示す線がどんどん膨れ上がってきました。 ブランチごとに表示させれば、履歴を追うのは特段難しいことではないのですが、All Branchesで全部のブランチの様子を見るのがつらいです。　このように線が膨れ上がらない方法はあるのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

gitk を使うのはどうでしょうか。適度に矢印で端折ってくれます。

(ちなみに、矢印をクリックすると、その対応する矢印へジャンプしてくれます。)

[image: gitk-screenshot]